# Is there a PVC piping primer/cement alternative for a non-plumbing project?

Tags: pvc

I'd like to construct a case out of PVC schedule-40 bits and pieces.  The case is for a rifle-cleaning rod that I want to keep from getting bent/scraped.  I'll need to connect schedule-40 pipe to caps/adapters/plugs/etc.

Is there something else I can use for the cement other than the traditional PVC primer and cement?

I'm too cheap to want to spend $15 on a can of each, as I'm unlikely to use them again in the future.  I'm hoping that I could use super glue or epoxy or something common, as I don't need this contraption to hold up under water pressure.

Comment: I have definitely seen smaller cans available for ~$6, if that helps your decision any. Another option is to use ABS instead of PVC, and you can just glue it without using primer.

Comment: Locking because if asked today, this would be considered a hobby project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how strong you want the joints, you could just push them together and leave it unglued.  I've done this to create poster tubes out of 3" PVC which went through airport baggage handling just fine.  PVC fittings are tapered on the inside, so the further in the pipe goes the stronger it will naturally hold.

If you want to use some glue, anything which will hold non-porous surfaces should work.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to find smaller/cheaper containers of glue.  You can definitely skip the primer for this application, using the PVC cement by itself will be plenty.

Answer (score 1):

Why do I get the impression that PVC adhesive makers are against disclosing any information that might diminish their profits? Going to Home Depot or Lowe's gives one sticker shock when it comes to these "glues", and I've found online some PVC adhesives for as little as $7 for a whole pint. MEK (abbreviation for the chemical name of its solvent) can be used to thin thickened  adhesive, which happens over time. A very small dab of Gorilla Glue would hold the joints of your PVC creation together just fine.

Comment: Oatey's consists of [10-25% MEK](http://www.oatey.com/msds/sds-us--pvc-medium-clear-cement.pdf), 10-25% Acetone and 30-50% Furan, another solvent. I'd say a combination of *jam it in there* and just about any solvent should work.